# Selecting the best employee data from a csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv

We have a nightly export from our employee information system containing transactions (updates) made in the last 24 hours (additions, deletions and changes).
Each transaction includes the transaction id, employee id, employee name, title, department, FTE, etc.
The export sometimes contains multiple entries for the same employee, usually when they split their time between two departments or are on a graduated return from leave.
What I'd like to do is either: a) select the department where they spend the most time, or b) merge the data between two entries.

New code:

```
# First, create a list from the file
file = list(csv.DictReader(open('extract_all_20240108.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8')))

# The reference row (to be compared to all other rows in the file)
for ref_row in file:
    # The check row (being compared to the reference row)
    for chk_row in file:
        if chk_row['X-ID'] > ref_row['X-ID']:                       # don't compare a row to itself
            if chk_row['Employee#'] == ref_row['Employee#']:        # look for a match to the employee ID
                print('Reference Row: '+ref_row['X-ID']+', Employee#: '+ref_row['Employee#']+', Location: '+ref_row['Location']+', FTE: '+ref_row['FTE'])
                print('Matched Row: '+chk_row['X-ID']+', Employee#: '+chk_row['Employee#']+', Location: '+chk_row['Location']+', FTE: '+chk_row['FTE'])
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
```

I now get the following output:

```
Reference Row: 10862, Employee#: 13897, Location: Elmer S Gish, FTE: 0.5176
Matched Row:   10877, Employee#: 13897, Location: Elmer S Gish, FTE: 0.5176
Reference Row: 10863, Employee#: 14264, Location: William D Cuts, FTE: 1.0000
Matched Row:   10881, Employee#: 14264, Location: William D Cuts, FTE: 1.0000
Reference Row: 10864, Employee#: 14596, Location: Wild Rose, FTE: 25.0000
Matched Row:   10882, Employee#: 14596, Location: Wild Rose, FTE: 25.0000
Reference Row: 10865, Employee#: 16216, Location: None, FTE: 0.0000
Matched Row:   10884, Employee#: 16216, Location: None, FTE: 0.0000
Reference Row: 10866, Employee#: 13711, Location: Elmer S Gish, FTE: 0.6379
Matched Row:   10886, Employee#: 13711, Location: Elmer S Gish, FTE: 0.6379
Reference Row: 10868, Employee#: 16210, Location: Joseph M Demko, FTE: 1.0000
Matched Row:   10888, Employee#: 16210, Location: Joseph M Demko, FTE: 1.0000
```

This gives me the data I need to move on to the logic portion to either merge the data or delete the row I don't want.

Comment: Hi , did the duplicate question that was linked help you?

Comment: Not really; it doesn't seem to address my specific case, and I'm trying to fumble my way around to get this to work.

Comment: You are iterating over the csv.reader more than once. After the first time you get no more rows out of it. If you want to iterate over the rows more than once you need to save them in a list.

Comment: Thanks. I've made some progress on this, thanks to you and the link to the duplicate question.